# Workbench - Column count doesn't match value count?

Tags: mysql, workbench

Im trying to insert values into a table using this syntax code, but it's displaying "column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, name, username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES ('Bonnie Buntcake','bbunt','6709 Wonder Street','Wonderbread','OH','46105','eclectic');
INSERT INTO users (userid,name,username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES ('Sam Smarf', 'ssmarf', '356 A Street', 'Beefy', 'PA', 19943, 'swimming');
INSERT INTO users (userid,name,username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES ('Wendy Grog', 'wgrog', '900 Star Street', 'Mary', 'MD', 21340, 'wells');
INSERT INTO users (userid,name,username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES ('Joe Jogger', 'jjogger', '183713 N North Street', 'Norther', 'WV', 51423, 'tarts');
```

**I also altered the tables to NOT NULL:**

```
ALTER TABLE locations MODIFY type INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE locations MODIFY description CHAR NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE locations MODIFY lng INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE locations MODIFY lat INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY userid INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY name CHAR NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY username CHAR NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY password CHAR NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE photograph MODIFY photoid INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE photograph MODIFY locationid INT NOT NULL;
```

[Here's a screenshot of the workbench tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trg2S.png)

Comment: You are not inserting a `userid` and you forgot to make `userid` into an AutoIncrement (AI) column

Answer (score 1):

It appears your `userid` column is intended to be an auto-increment primary key but I do not see the `AI` attribute checked in the Workbench image.

Add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute to `userid`.

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY userid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Also, you have no character lengths or length of `(1)` on some of your `CHAR` columns. They will need to be longer than that or they will be truncated. I recommend using `VARCHAR()` instead, with an appropriate maximum length.

```
-- For a 32 character username
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY username VARCHAR(32);
-- Allow a large size for passwords - hashing algorithms might make them long
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY password VARCHAR(128);
```

Finally to the column count not matching... This is because you have included `userid` in your column list in the `INSERT` but did not include a value for it in the `VALUES()` list. The columns list has 8 columns but `VALUES()` only 7 values. There are 2 solutions.

Either omit `userid` from the column list so that MySQL fills it in automatically with an incrementing value:

```
-- Leave `userid` out
INSERT INTO users (name, username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES ('Bonnie Buntcake','bbunt','6709 Wonder Street','Wonderbread','OH','46105','eclectic');
```

Or leave `userid` in but supply a `NULL` in the `VALUES()` list. MySQL will also replace the `NULL` with an auto-increment value

```
-- Add a NULL to `VALUES()` in the position of `userid`
INSERT INTO users (userid, name, username,address,city,state,zip,password) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Bonnie Buntcake','bbunt','6709 Wonder Street','Wonderbread','OH','46105','eclectic');
```